# Error 'No Argument corresponds to required formal parameter CustomWebUi' when using PlatformParameters class

Tags: c#, active-directory, access-token

I'm using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to generate access token through AcquireTokenAsync() method.

But while using PlatformParameters, if I don't give a second argument I get this error **There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'customWebUi' of 'PlatformParameters.PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior, ICustomWebUi)**

Although there is an option of using only one argument in the documentation.

```
var resourceurl = Resourceurl.GetValue(dc.State);
var clientid = Clientid.GetValue(dc.State);
var redirecturl = new Uri(Redirecturl.GetValue(dc.State));

var authenticationcontext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize");
var parameters = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);

var result = authenticationcontext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceurl,clientid,redirecturl,parameters).CreateAuthorizationHeader();
```

This is the code snippet

Comment: Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: Yes,it means I need to pass another argument in PlatformParameters() but as I said the documentation has the method with one argument only and I don't know what should go in this argument

Comment: Perhaps you could point us to the docs?

Comment: [PlatformParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.platformparameters?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: You are using the version of the package mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Yes, he is I guess. I came to the same problem. There is a constructor with PromptBehaviour only, but actually there is not.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you have to use .Net Framework instead of .Net Core Framework

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, it's recommended to post answers like this as post comment, so when you'll reach enough reputation (50 rep.), please use the comments

Answer (score 0):

try to use this, for me it worked!
Target Framework .NET 4.6.2, if you don´t get it from the dropdown in project settings you can open the .csproj and change it here:

```
<TargetFramework>net4.6.2</TargetFramework>
```