# Generate user token from AuthenticationContext

Tags: c#, authorization, token

I am trying to generate a user token for the purpose of testing an API that requires one. The tests run automatically. I have the following code example, but it seems to be out of date

```
  Uri endpointUri = new Uri("my endpoint");
  string resource = "my rid";
  string clientId = "my client id";
  PlatformParameters parameters = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);

  string authContextURL = "my url";

  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL, new TokenCache());

  // Here you are sending a request to AAD with the user credentials. 
  AuthenticationResult result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: resource, clientId: clientId, redirectUri: endpointUri, parameters);

  // If the request succeeded you can get the user access token as follows.
  return result.AccessToken;
```

The reason I believe it to be out of date is that `PlatformParameters` now requires 2 parameters, and I cannot find what the 2nd parameter should be by default.

My question is, how can I create a user-context token to use in testing my API from the test code?

**EDIT**
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63616910/14492841), `PlatformParameters` with 1 param is for .netframework, whereas I am using .net 6
Still looking to any leads there may be!

Comment: Looks the same as msdn example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-app-dev-net?force_isolation=true#authentication  See important : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-app-dev-net?force_isolation=true#create-your-project-and-add-nuget-packages

Comment: Are you sure you have included the correct NuGet packages?